# net application/web server separation

Tags: java, .net, architecture

In the Java world, I often see separation between web server and application server.  The idea is to scale out your "relatively" cheap web server easily and beef up your application server when needed.

However, I don't see this setup in the .NET/windows 2008 world all the much, why is that?  One argument against this architecture in the .NET world would be the licensing cost of IIS7/W28.  Is there any reason why .net developer/architects are not going after this design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no clear concept of "Application Server" in .NET. Also .NET is very good "integrated" with OS
We can say that so far the role of application server was on IIS and Windows.
You get almost everything you need packed in .NET framework itself.

Also note that from April 2010 you can use AppFabric which is Application Server. I have started evaluation of this product and it looks to be really good. 
So if you are interested in application server for .NET please have a look at AppFabric.

Comment: I think the fact that there is no clear concept of "application server" in .NET development environment is because we need IIS to run and kind of web content, be it *.aspx or *.html.  This is good in a sense that every is "integrated" together.  However, the down side is that there is no way to separate the web and application side of you app.

Comment: Starting from IIS 7 you can. Since you have IIS7, WAS and AppFabric.
You can use "Classical" IIS as a Web Server and AppFabric as an application server. Please check more info about them it will make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it adds complexity to your architecture with minimal benefit. You will see a much larger boost to application performance by beefing up your database.